# Swift Custom TableViewCells only appearing in stack view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a simple TableView with a custom cell that has two labels and an image. Everything is linked correctly between my custom cell class and the storyboard itself, but when things run on the simulator it just doesn't show up. Eventually I put them in a stack view just because, and it turned out to work. This makes no sense to me as why would a stack view make something appear but without it they don't even appear as the wrong size. Here are two pictures showing the cell with and without the stack view and what it looks like when executed.

**Before**
[image]
[image]

**After**
[image]
[image]

Not sure what the problem is or how to fix it.

The layout for my project is width-Any and height-Regular

Comment: You seem to be using auto layout but for iOS 9 you can't mix and match views with auto layout and those without and expect a good result. The stack view is adding some constraints, but you should also add constraints between your stack view and its superview. If you want your cells subviews to be laid out like they are in the prototype cell you should say something like `cell.contentView.subviews.forEach{ $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true }` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I believe I am using the same autolayout for the entire project, same for every view. Is this still a problem? Not completely sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean your prototype table view cell has no constraints, but maybe your table view does. So when the layout engine does a pass it sets all of the subviews' frames to zero, so they don't show up. All of the views in a view hierarchy need to have constraints that satisfy the layout engine, or they need to opt out by `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true`.

Comment: Where do I put something like what you mentioned in your first comment within my View Controller class?

Comment: I would recommend adding constraints to you table view cell, as then your cell would be resizable and work on all screen sizes, but you could add it to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or in your table view cell subclass in `awakeFromNib` for all of your IBOutlets set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to true.

Comment: I added some constraints but the cells still show up empty when run. Here is a picture of the constraints. http://imgur.com/pywSH98

Comment: Try printing the frames of your subviews in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and look at your views with this [thing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html).

Comment: How can I print the frames of my subviews?

Comment: If you launch the view hierarchy inspector as mentioned in the link above you can just right click and say print description. Or you can do it the caveman way and say `print(cell.label.frame)` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`